# Database Normalization

Tags: database, relational-database, normalization, database-schema, database-normalization

I have had a crack at normalizing some data for a database would appreciate if anyone body could tell me if its correctly normalized.
Here is the structure:

[image]

I have used a composite key(Incident ID and Action code) as a certain incident would not require two actions of the same type. Is there a better way of doing this? I thought about just adding an Action ID auto number but is this OK?

Thanks if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would use ActionID as my key - it really depends on what you'll be doing with the data and the volume.

I could see it being useful to get a list of incidents where you'd taken out a particular Action, this would be easier to get with an index on just Action Code, also having a composite key could well result in page splits on the clustered index which obviously has an overhead.

Comment: Hi Andy, Thanks for the feedback. Should I add Action ID to UNF and normalize again? As this needs to be documented I don't believe I can justify generating a ActionID during 1/2NF?

Comment: I really wouldn't get too hung-up on 1st 2nd 3rd NF - as they say "normalise until it hurts and then de-normalise until it works".  I'd just add ActionID to your Action table, obviously I don't know what your requirements are in terms of documentation, But if you have to document the steps to 3nf, I would seriously question it as what's wrong with 4NF, 5NF etc?

Comment: Thanks again Andy. It does need to normalized to "3NF or BCNF". Adding the action ID should only effect the 2NF slightly though. Thanks, Simon

Comment: Normalization *never* involves creating *new* columns ex nihilo.

Comment: No but I could add Action ID to UNF ?